# how to solve connection exeception in jemeter

Tags: jmeter

I have creatd on jemter script to record the webpage. here i perform below steps to record the script

1. Created the ThradGroup
2. Add HttpRequestDefault
3. Add Recording Conroller
4. Add HttpTestScript(s)Recorder
5. View Result Tree Listener

Here script gets recorded. but while running the script throws exception

```
 Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException
 Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection refused:
```

[image: WebsiteTesingRecorder]

Comment: did you stop recording?

Comment: @KirilS. Yes sir i stopped the recording but found that service is not resopnding.